# Linear regression in an array in python

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression, sympy

I have a one dimensional numpy array of symbolic equations and a one dimensional numpy array of values like this:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
E = sp.Symbol('E')

values = np.array([0.0, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0007, 0.0009, 0.0011, 0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0017, 0.0019, 0.0021, 0.0024, 0.0026, 0.0028, 0.0031, 0.0033, 0.0036, 0.0038, 0.0041, 0.0043, 0.0046])
equations = np.array([27405854.8989427/E, 106962058.905272/E, 234787976.631598/E, 407151513.555005/E, 620469116.017057/E, 871305771.223787/E, 1156375007.24571/E, 1472538893.01782/E, 1816808038.33958/E, 2186341593.87493/E, 2578447251.15228/E, 2990581242.5645/E, 3420348341.36898/E, 3865501861.68755/E, 4323943658.50655/E, 4793724127.67675/E, 5273042205.91346/E, 5760245370.79641/E, 6253829640.76983/E, 6752439575.14242/E, 7254868274.08736/E, 7760057378.64231/E, 8267097070.70941/E, 8775226073.05526/E, 9283831649.31095/E])
```

I am trying to find a single value of E that will give me the least amount of error with respect to each of the elements in the second array of values when substituted in the array of equations.

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Yea that should be easy if you post your numbers in a way I can copy them.

Comment: Since you basically have `a / E = b`, which is the same as `E = a / b`, [numpy.linalg.lstsq()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) may be useful. (It's also in Scipy.) There are lots of examples online of how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scipy provides a method for minimizing a scalar function. So we just write an error function and let it do the rest.

```
values = np.array([0.0, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0007, 0.0009, 0.0011, 0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0017, 0.0019, 0.0021, 0.0024, 0.0026, 0.0028, 0.0031, 0.0033, 0.0036, 0.0038, 0.0041, 0.0043, 0.0046])
equations = np.array([2.74058549e+07, 1.06962059e+08, 2.34787977e+08, 4.07151514e+08,
       6.20469116e+08, 8.71305771e+08, 1.15637501e+09, 1.47253889e+09,
       1.81680804e+09, 2.18634159e+09, 2.57844725e+09, 2.99058124e+09,
       3.42034834e+09, 3.86550186e+09, 4.32394366e+09, 4.79372413e+09,
       5.27304221e+09, 5.76024537e+09, 6.25382964e+09, 6.75243958e+09,
       7.25486827e+09, 7.76005738e+09, 8.26709707e+09, 8.77522607e+09,
       9.28383165e+09])

def error(E):
    return np.mean(np.abs(equations/(np.abs(E)+10**(-20))-values))

minimize_scalar(error)
```

Notice that I wrote the function to avoid dividing by zero. The relevant values should be very large so the `10**-20` will not make a difference.

And it gives you `x: 2018224283062.8733`.

Btw. if you are happy with mean squared error instead of mean absolute error. (Other than the absolute value squaring keeps things differentiable.) You can do it with sympy too.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
E = sp.Symbol('E')

values = np.array([0.0, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0003, 0.0004, 0.0006, 0.0007, 0.0009, 0.0011, 0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0017, 0.0019, 0.0021, 0.0024, 0.0026, 0.0028, 0.0031, 0.0033, 0.0036, 0.0038, 0.0041, 0.0043, 0.0046])
equations = np.array([27405854.8989427/E, 106962058.905272/E, 234787976.631598/E, 407151513.555005/E, 620469116.017057/E, 871305771.223787/E, 1156375007.24571/E, 1472538893.01782/E, 1816808038.33958/E, 2186341593.87493/E, 2578447251.15228/E, 2990581242.5645/E, 3420348341.36898/E, 3865501861.68755/E, 4323943658.50655/E, 4793724127.67675/E, 5273042205.91346/E, 5760245370.79641/E, 6253829640.76983/E, 6752439575.14242/E, 7254868274.08736/E, 7760057378.64231/E, 8267097070.70941/E, 8775226073.05526/E, 9283831649.31095/E])

error = np.mean((equations-values)**2)
sp.solve(error.diff(E))
```

giving you

```
[2027858708334.55]
```

And a simple mathy argument would tell you that must be the global minimum. If you're interested in it I can add that.